# Rails3 dynamic_form plugin not recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, dynamic-forms

Using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3 -

When attempting to use `<%= error_messages_for 'story' %>` I get this error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: error_messages_for was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin. Please install it with `rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/dynamic_form.git`. (called from _app_views_stories_new_html_erb__1042605186_33967248__100840187 at C:/Ruby192/shovell/app/views/stories/new.html.erb:1)
```

So I did what it said and ran the plugin install. However now I have an empty dynamic_form folder at `vendor/plugins`. I tried using `http` instead of `git` with no luck. I also added a `/` at the end of the URL which worked for someone else online, but with no luck.

I added `gem dynamic_form` to the `Gemfile` and `require "dynamic_form"` to the `application.rb` as well as rerun `bundle install`. It shows that dynamic_form-1.1.3 is installed to `lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/' but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: If you're having trouble using the normal git install, you can probably just download from github, and extract to vendor/plugins. Alternatively, if you're installing as a gem, you should be adding `gem 'dynamic_form'` to your `Gemfile` and running bundle install, that's how specifying gems and requiring them works in rails 3.

Comment: I downloaded the source from Github and had no luck...is the source the right collection or is there a singular file somewhere that i missed? As for the Gem part, that is exactly what I did,as I mentioned, but it didn't seem to recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was as Jeremy pointed out, to simply download rails/dynamic_form on github and extract it to `vendor/plugins` and rename the folder "dynamic_form". The reason it didn't work for me before was because I was using someone else's modified version of dynamic form and of course not specifying it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was trying to use `dynamic_form` inside of a Rails Engine that I was building.

I simply added the `gem 'dynamic_form'` into my `Gemfile`, did a `bundle install` and added

```
require 'dynamic_form'
```

inside my `lib/libname.rb`. Restarted the app, and all was well.

Comment: I didn't need to add require 'dynamic_form' bundle install was all I needed.