# rails - Devise - Creating a Registration Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I've been banging my head against the wall try to understand how to get Devise to work with customer registration....

So On my landing page I want to show a registration form, so I added this to my view:

```
<%= render 'devise/registrations/new' %>
```

In that partial I have in the view a form tag like follows:

```
<%= form_for(user_registration_path, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
.
.
```

In my application layout I have:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="flash <%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

The issue I'm having is when I submit a new registration form with invalid params, I don't see the error message?

But if I submit valid info the form does say it worked and that I need to check my email for the confirmation link, which is good.

Can you help me understand how to get this working end-2-end so I can display the errors:

Here's my full controller:

```
  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.xml                                            
  # GET /users/new.json                                    HTML AND AJAX
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------
  def new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @user }   
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
      format.html
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit                                                      
  # GET /users/1/edit.xml                                                      
  # GET /users/1/edit.json                                HTML AND AJAX
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------
  def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @user }   
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
      format.html
    end

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    respond_to_not_found(:json, :xml, :html)
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.xml         
  # POST /users.json                                      HTML AND AJAX
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => @user.to_json, :status => 200 }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { redirect_to :action => :index }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :text => "Could not create user", :status => :unprocessable_entity } # placeholder
        format.xml  { head :ok }
        format.html { render :action => :new, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The model:

```
  validates :fname, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
  validates :lname, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 2 }
  validates :password, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 6 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the github readme:
"Remember that Devise uses flash messages to let users know if sign in was successful or failed. Devise expects your application to call "flash[:notice]" and "flash[:alert]" as appropriate."

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `<%= error_messages_for %>`? That is how errors will be displayed.

Also, devise needs virtual attributes in the model for additional attributes so don't forget to add `:lname`, `:fname` etc... to the devise user model or whatever you are doing.

---

Update

```
<%= f.error_messages_for :model %>
```

Before Rails 3 this is how errors were formatted, but in R3 it's depircated and you need to install a plugin to access errors this way. See comments for the link to the plugin

Comment: What is <%= error_messages_for %>? where and how does that go? Can you give me the full example so I can test it out? Thanks

Comment: "DEPRECATION WARNING: error_messages_for was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin"

Comment: below Rails 3 `f.error_messages_for :model` was how to access errors, and that is why you are not getting any error output here. It is deprecated but looks like a number of people are still using it though this plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102479/rails3-dynamic-form-not-recognized

Answer (score 0):

Just insert this at the beginning of your form, end before the end of it:

```
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

Devise is kinda tricky, I just finally managed to figure it out myself, and it's awesome. Btw, don't render the view as a partial, use templates, and then set your root to `users#registrations_controller`, given that you created custom controllers and views.

If you haven't, I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://blog.payload.tech/2016/03/18/custom-routes-and-views-with-devise/)