# Rails undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that i want to appear at the top of every page so i've included it in the /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file and i get the error `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class` when trying to load the page.

Here's the form snippet in application.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <h3>Add new contact</h3>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <hr />
    <%= f.submit "Add Contact" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my /app/controllers/user_controller.rb

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

    def index

    end

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

end
```

I'm thinking that i'm hitting this error because since the form is in the application.html.erb file, i need to somehow specify the path, but then again i'm very new to rails.

Let me know if you need anything else posted.

**EDIT**
Following Ola's suggestion, In my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file I have something like this:

```
<div>
<%= yield :add_user %>
</div>
```

and in my app/views/users/new.html.erb file I have this

```
<% content_for :add_user do %>
    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
        <h3>Add new contact</h3>
        First Name<br />
        <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
        Last Name<br />
        <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />
        Email<br />
        <%= f.text_field :email %>
        <hr />
        <%= f.submit "Add Contact" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The form is not rendered because my url is `http://localhost:3000/admin/index` and so it's looking for the `add_user` content_for in app/views/admin/index.html.erb

Comment: I presume "when trying to load the page" you mean `/users`

Comment: Sorry actually i'm loading this page `http://localhost:3000/admin/index`

Comment: Yes, I thought as much, in the example above `/users/new` should work (kind of), though you've got your view structure all wrong - see my answer below.

Comment: I'm afraid you've got the `yield` directive upside down too - trust me I know how confusing all this stuff is when you first hit the rails. <%= yield :something %> will render *output from the current action*, which would vary depending on what page you're on. Great for when you want each controller/action to set the contents of some universal page element (often used to set the document title) but you actually want the complete opposite - to render some component the same on every page. For this you should use `<%= render :partial => "thing/partial" %>` in your template.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the form is included for multiple actions (pages) you need to set `@user` to something or the `form_for` directive will fail (it won't have anything to create a form *for*).

A much better approach (and the Rails default) is to have separate views for each action, each including only the elements required by that action, and loaded into your `application.html.erb` layout with `<%= yield %>`. So you would have a `app/views/users/new.html.erb` view which has the form in it. You <strike>never</strike> very rarely need to define any load paths in Rails, they are all derived from the model, controller and action names - or from your `routes.rb`. This is a core part of the *[convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)* paradigm which runs so deep in Rails.

**Edit:** If you *do* need to have a form for creating a new object on every page (often used for UserSessions for example), you can rewrite your `form_for` so that it doesn't depend on an object being present:

```
form_for(User.new)
```

or if you need to force it to post to the `create` method

```
form_for(User.new, :url => { :action => "create" })
```

You can read more about resource driven `form_for` in the [Ruby On Rails API docs.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style)

Comment: So putting the form in app/views/users/new.html.erb gets the page  loaded, but now the form does not appear. I've updated my question with details.

Comment: Yes, as I don't know what your needs are I just assumed you had a standard CRUD page structure - see my edit above if you indeed need to have the form present on pages outside the User scope.

Comment: In this case I would put the form in a partial view (say `/app/views/users/_inline_form.hmtl.erb`) and load it in the `application.html.erb` layout with `<%= render :partial => 'users/inline_form' %>` (note the absence of the leading "_").

Comment: Just did that and now it gives me a undefined_model name error again.

Comment: If i try the other way you suggested and user `form_for(User.new)`, i get an `undefined method `users_path'` error.

Comment: `form_for(User.new, :url => { :action => "create", :controller => 'devise/registrations'})` was the magic ticker since i'm using the devise gem (which i probably should have mentioned previously).

Comment: Bingo! If you're using Devise though, you might as well use the routes it creates for you - so just do `<%= form_tag(user_registration_path) do %>` Devise sets up these routes for you. You can check what routes are available with `rake routes` at a command prompt. Also see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119921/rails-devise-creating-a-registration-form).

Answer (score 13):

Did you try debugging first? I ask because you say you are new to Rails. If not, here is my approach. I want to share it, because I'm surprised how many people don't (for whatever reason) debug carefully.

(I created a test app so that I could walk through your problem. First, I visited `http://localhost:3000/users`.)

First, look at the stack trace.

> NoMethodError in Users#index
>
> Showing /Users/david/dev/testapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #11
>   raised:
>
> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
>   Extracted source (around line #11):

```
8: </head>
9: <body>
10: 
11: <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
12:     <h3>Add new contact</h3>
13:     <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
14:     <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
```

This tells you line 11 in your code is the problem. Think -- what could be the issue? Routing is unlikely because you are just rendering the page. Not a syntax error, that would have triggered another error. Ok, so keep reading:

> Rails.root: /Users/david/dev/testapp
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Now click "framework trace" and you will see:

> activemodel (3.2.6) lib/active_model/naming.rb:163:in `model_name_from_record_or_class'
>   activemodel (3.2.6) lib/active_model/naming.rb:158:in`param_key'
>   actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:369:in `form_for'

You may not understand all this -- few people do -- but you will see the error comes from `model_name_from_record_or_class` which comes from `param_key` which comes from `form_for`. That is a big clue!

I recommend the use of the `open_gem` gem to make it easy to dig into source code:

```
gem install open_gem
```

Now, take a look at activemodel, since it is the topmost gem in the stack trace:

```
gem open activemodel
```

Now, search for this with regular expression searching enabled:

> def .*model_name_from_record_or_class

(Why? you want to find class methods -- e.g. definitions that start with `self` as well.)

This will take you to line 162 in `naming.rb`.

```
def self.model_name_from_record_or_class(record_or_class)
  (record_or_class.is_a?(Class) ? record_or_class : convert_to_model(record_or_class).class).model_name
end
```

Even without understanding all of this, it does give a big hint... the method tries to return the model name from the record or class. Why can't it? Because the parameter you are passing, `@user`, hasn't been set. The value of unset instance variables is nil, so it won't complain until you try to do something with it.

I hope this helps for this question and for future ones.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is really just Someth's answer corrected, but the solution is to set `@user` for every controller action, not just those pertaining to a specific controller. This can be done by using a `before_filter` in the ApplicationController, i.e.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :initialize_user

  def initialize_user
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

*OR* by creating a new model in the form_for helper itself (note: this is ugly in terms of separation of concerns, but it works...)

```
 <%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
   <h3>Add new contact</h3>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
   <hr />
   <%= f.submit "Add Contact" %>
 <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to add form to every action on your page, but didn't initialize user in all action. Try to initialize user in all actions:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :initialize_user

    def index

    end

    def initialize_user
        @user = User.new
    end

end
```

Comment: That won't quite work - since he's got the form in `application.hmtl.erb` he would need to put the code in ApplicationController instead, or any page outide the UserController scope would still give the error. But that's academic; he's got his view structure in a tangle and should refactor!

Comment: Ola is spot on. The filter should be in the ApplicationController, since it should be executed for every page.

Answer (score 0):

in the usercontroller:

```
def index
   @user = User.new
end
```