# How do I display a form_for within an iterator in a view? | ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display a form from another controller in a view within an iterator.

Every time I try to run the code it gives me an error:
'NoMethodError at /undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass'

I tried displaying the form by rendering a partial with the form from another controller and I've also tried rendering a partial with the form within the same controller but both return an error. This is might be because it's within iterator for another collection?

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>

  <div class='service-info'>
    <%= service.name %>
    <%= service.description %>
  </div>

  <%= simple_form_for(@visit) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: 
    f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence 
    if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

    <%= f.input :service %>
    <%= f.input :visit_date %>
    <%= f.input :note %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I would like the 'visit' form to appear below each 'service' in the view.

Comment: Can you please post what error you are getting

Comment: I am getting this error: NoMethodError at /
undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Seems like `@visit` is somewhere `nil`. You best way to solve would be adding a debugger to it and check for the values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails undefined method \`model\_name' for NilClass:Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093848/rails-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass)

Comment: It is not a duplicate.